# Resolution dependent image in ListView

Tags: firemonkey

How to put an image with proper scale from `TImageList` source with different scales of images into image in `TListView`?

Comment: Just use ListView.Images and ListItem.ImageIndex. All the rest will do the TImageList :)

Comment: can you provide me a part of code, please? can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You should set properties **Images** and **ImageIndex**. The scale will be selected automatically. [See ImageListDemo.dproj](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/FMX.ImageList_Sample)

Comment: please post an answer, then references